# Exclude Weekends and Public Holidays in DATEDIFF Measure using PowerBI

Tags: if-statement, powerbi

Im trying to exclude Weekends and Public Holidays for the PowerBi Measure below,

```
First Report = IF(abs(DATEDIFF(C[CreatedDate].[Date],C[Earliest Date max per ID],DAY)+1)<=2,"OnTime","Late")
```

Basically what the Measure should check if the difference between these dates are equals to or less than a day excluding weekends and public holidays.
Im not sure how to modify this Measure in a way that it excludes weekends and public holiday. I've tried creating calendar table but not sure how to proceed from there. Would highly appreciate if someone could help me out

Answer (score 2):

Create a table, name it **Public_Holiday** & enter Public Holidays dates manually or maybe from excel or any other source.
Crete a blank query in query editor and paste this M code in advance editor. I am assuming Sat & Sunday to be excluded.

```
(StartDate as date, EndDate as date) as number =>
let
List.Dates = List.Dates(StartDate, Number.From(EndDate-StartDate)+1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
RemoveWeekends = List.Select(List.Dates, each Date.DayOfWeek(_,Day.Monday)<5),
RemoveHolidays = List.RemoveItems(RemoveWeekends, Public_Holiday),
CountDays = List.Count(RemoveHolidays)
in
CountDays
```

Call this function anytime you need to get working days in query editor.

Comment: I've created a query and table as instructed but how do I implement M query into this Measure?

`First Report = IF(abs(DATEDIFF(C[CreatedDate].[Date],C[Earliest Date max per ID],DAY)+1)<=2,"OnTime","Late")`


M Query
`M = (StartDate as date, EndDate as date) as number...........`

Comment: You cannot implement M query to Measure. Measure does not belong to any table. Lets say you want to calculate duration between **Start** & **End** column in any table, first create a query as advised above and name it **networkdays**. Now add a custom column in query editor and write the expression as below
**=networkdays([Start],[End])**

Comment: I believe this cant be done cause C[Earliest Date max per ID] is a calculated column. Is there a way to exclude weekends and public holiday only using Measure?

Comment: NETWORKDAYS was recently introduced with Latest Power BI released in Jul 2022. 
Update your Power BI to latest version and use DAX function: NETWORKDAYS.
More info below

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-my/blog/power-bi-july-2022-feature-summary/

Comment: okay I've managed to create a measure using NETWORKDAYS. One last question, I've done this Measure but its showing the  reports submitted on July 21st 2022 and July 22nd 2022 as a late. By right it should display as ON TIME based on the Measure. Could you help on this pls?

` Report = IF((NETWORKDAYS(C[CreatedDate].[Date],C[Latest Date max per ID],1,Public_Holiday))<=2,"OnTime","Late")`

Comment: @Avi didn't know about the update, so, thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
VAR allDates= DATESBETWEEN ( 'Date'[Date], StartDate, EndDate )
-- VAR allDates = GENERATESERIES ( StartDate, EndDate , 1 ) -- If you don't have a Calendar table 
                                                            -- and you need to check all dates in period.
                                                            -- It can create another column name for Filter()
VAR allDatesExceptHolidays = EXCEPT(allDates,VALUES('Holydays'[Date]))
VAR allDatesExceptHolidaysNoWeekend=
        FILTER(
            allDatesExceptHolidays 
            ,WEEKDAY([Date],2)<6
        )
VAR DaysQty = COUNTROWS(allDatesExceptHolidaysNoWeekend)

RETURN 
    DaysQty
```